# website with openid, facebook connect

Tags: java, google-app-engine, facebook, openid

My Google app engine java website uses opendid to login, and I plan to add facebook connect.
Any thought of how to save the openid/facebook userid elegantly?

Comment: How do you currently store the openids with accounts? I would recommend a database to store "users" and then a "logins" table so users can associate multiple openids and facebook ids with a single account.

Comment: Typeonerror, that looks like an answer to me.